# What would the MVC and overall structure for a command line interface look like in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, command-line, command-line-interface, swift4

For example my app will have a database (model), text based interface(view) and behaviour (view controller) as well as data retrieval from network sources. I still don't know how to create main event loops, create notifications or listen for events (save that for the next question) but just want to get the structure right.

So far I have:

> main.swift

This would have to be the setup for the main event loop which I have no idea how to do; so using NSApplication.

```
import AppKit

let app = NSApplication.shared
app.delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApp.run()
```

> AppDelegate.swift

```
import AppKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let viewController = ViewController()
        let dataBase = DataBase()
        let networking = Networking()
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    }
}
```

> ViewController.swift

Which I'm guessing needs to have it's own event loop and listening for keypresses from the view.

```
class ViewController {
    let view = View()
    func update() {
        view.display()
    }
}
```

> View.swift

Which isn't supposed to hold data only layout but does contain default labels.

```
class View {
    let clear = "\u{001B}[3J"
    let title1 = "app:\n"
    let title2 = "message log:\n"
    var log: [String] = ["welcome to app!"]
    var menu: [String] = ["o = open", "f = find items", "v = verify items"]
    let question = "enter option followed by return:"
    var input: String?
    func display() {
        print(clear)
        print(title1)
        print(title2)
        if log.count < 10 {
            for text in stride(from: 0, to: log.count, by: 1) {
                print("\(text + 1): \(log[text])")
            }
        } else {
            for text in stride(from: log.count - 10, to: log.count, by: 1) {
                print("\(text + 1): \(log[text])")
            }
        }
        print()
        if menu.count != 0 {
            print("menu: ", terminator: "")
            for option in stride(from: 0, to: menu.count - 1, by: 1) {
                print("\(menu[option])", terminator: ", ")
            }
            print("\(menu[menu.count - 1])", terminator: "\n")
        }
        print(question, terminator: " ")
        input = readLine()
    }
}
```

> Database.swift

```
import Foundation

class Item: Codable {
    let url: URL
    let dateAdded: Date
    var dateModified: Date
    var isReal: Bool?
    var isRealChecked: Date?
    var lowestPrice: Double?
    var medianPrice: Double?
    var volumeSold24Hr: Int?
    init (_ url: String) {
        self.url = URL(string: url)!
        self.dateAdded = Date()
        self.dateModified = Date()
    }
}
```

> Networking.swift

This would contain the code that grabs my data structure from the net.

Comment: This is not a command line interface, that's a full-fledged application. CLIs don't have any UI.

Comment: @vadian Couldn't the output from the print command be the UI of the CLI? And when notified by the controller the CLI could be cleared and updated with new content from another call to the print command?